# Using objects to discriminate union types

Tags: typescript, union-types

I am trying to create union types in TypeScript where the discriminator is a value on a nested object, rather than a primitive value directly on the type. I am working with objects returned from an API and therefore cannot alter the data structures being returned.

Is this possible in TypeScript, without needing to resort to user-defined type guards?

Here is a simplified example:

```
type SquareIdentifier = {
  type: "square";
};

type CircleIdentifier = {
  type: "circle";
};

type SquareShape = {
  identifier: SquareIdentifier;
  sideLength: number;
};

type CircleShape = {
  identifier: CircleIdentifier;
  diameter: number;
};

type Shape = SquareShape | CircleShape;

// assume we have been given a variable `x` of Shape
const x = ({} as any) as Shape;

// at this point, x.identifier is considered a SquareIdentifier | CircleIdentifier
if (x.identifier.type === "square") {
  // at this point, x.identifier is considered a SquareIdentifier
  // however, x is still considered a Shape, not a SquareShape, which is the only Shape to contain a ShapeIdentifier
  // error here is:
  // "Property 'sideLength' does not exist on type 'Shape'"
  // "Property 'sideLength' does not exist on type 'CircleShape'"
  console.log(x.sideLength);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to use [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

For example like this:

```
if (isSquareShape(x)) {
  console.log(x.sideLength);
}

function isSquareShape(value: Shape): value is SquareShape {
    return value.identifier.type === 'square';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of Type Guards but was hoping for a solution that doesn't require them. It seems odd that TypeScript wouldn't be capable of discriminating based on the above example.

Comment: Looks like TypeScript doesn’t support what I’m after. I’ll use the type guards and maybe make a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you need with [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
type SquareIdentifier = {
  type: "square";
};

type CircleIdentifier = {
  type: "circle";
};

type SquareShape = {
  identifier: SquareIdentifier;
  sideLength: number;
};

type CircleShape = {
  identifier: CircleIdentifier;
  diameter: number;
};

type Shape = SquareShape | CircleShape;

const isSquareShape = (x: any): x is SquareShape => {
    return x.type && x.type === 'sqaure';
}
const testFunction = (x: any) => {
    if (isSquareShape(x)) {
        const y = x.sideLength; // this now works, because typescript 'knows' we have a square shape
    }
}
```

The function `isSquareShape` allows typescript to determine that a value is of type `SquareShape`, and so once we have code which passes the value through this check (`if (isSquareShape(x))`, in this instance) we're able to access the value as though it were a `SquareShape` with no type errors.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of Type Guards but was hoping for a solution that doesn't require them. It seems odd that TypeScript wouldn't be capable of discriminating based on the above example.

Comment: It seems like typescript could be capable of working that out in theory but I'm not sure in practice how that'd work - type guards are designed for exactly this sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I would use `in` operator type guard:

```js
type Shape = SquareShape | CircleShape;
// assume we have been given a variable `x` of Shape
const x = ({} as any) as Shape;

if ('sideLength' in x) {
  // x is inferred as SquareShape
  console.log(x.sideLength);
}
```